# App error . Attribute error with first application

Tags: django, django-forms, drupal-modules

I have created this app in django but i cannot access the app . CMD says 
Attribute error : module 'hello.views' has no attribute 'index'

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World !!!')
```

URLS.PY/admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('hello.urls'))
```

]

URLS.PY/Hello

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put commas after `path()`.

```
path('hello/', views.index, name='index'), # Very important comma.
```

I think you missed one in each file.

I now see the other problem. Change your hello.urls.py path to

```
path('',
```

Your current configuration is looking for

```
/hello/hello/
```

If you put that in your browser it might work.

Comment: i changed it , the problem persistes

Comment: You got the one in urls.py/admin?

Comment: I changed my answer.